# How to filter "number + letter" records with extracting numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

```
A : 12 or less
B : 13
C : 14
D : 15 or more
E : 12 or less
F : 13
```

If I sort it by ascend it will be like this

```
B : 13
F : 13
C : 14
A : 12 or less
E : 12 or less
D : 15 or more
```

I used to put `'` infront of numbers to change the type from numeric to letters to achieve this,
but this time the files too large that I don't want to make this effort.

Second thing that came to my mind was to add another column and use `substitute()` and filter with that column.
But I also want to avoid this method as `12` and `12 or less` can co-exist in certain situation and trying to give those records sorting numbers gives me a headache.

TL;DR: How do I select the numbers that are mixed with letters, and sort by them?

Comment: So what should happen if '12' and '12 or less' co-exist? Should 12 or less come first? Are there other letters that could follow the numbers?

Comment: the reason why it coexists is that I screwed up in a google form and surveyed 6000+ before I changed it :(  I think less should come first.

Comment: **unclear** Please update your question to show the **desired** result of the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the below result is really what you want, you can use a "helper column" for sorting, then delete it.

The Helper column formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ")-1)+  SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"less","more"},A1))*{-0.4,0.4})
```

*With formula*

[image]

*After sorting*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First Select the data you wish to sort and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub TextMaker()
    Dim cell As Range, v As String
    For Each cell In Selection
        v = cell.Text
        cell.Clear
        cell.NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Value = v
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Then sort manually:

[image]